# What is the minimum SDK version should I choose? (as in Nov 2018)

Tags: android, android-min-sdk

As I am aware, default min SDK set in android studio is 15. I have read that I should increase it as there aren't many (or maybe none) who is still using that android version. Plus, I am planning to use some new features in android studio which only works in higher API.

May I know, as for now what would be your minimum SDK version, so as to guide me choose mine.

Comment: It is really up to you. Just use the lowest SDK that supports the features you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/) may answer your question. It contains the most accurate distribution of Android versions with an average delta of 7 days. The current page claims :

> Data collected during a 7-day period ending on October 26, 2018.

So you're pretty accurate with this.

To answer your question, based on the dashboard, targeting the **API version 19 will cover 96.5% of all current Android devices worldwide**

Comment: Great documentation, with evidence based data. Hopefully they will keep it updated over time.

Comment: It has been maintained since the very early versions of Android, so IMO it will probably keep on going this way

Answer (score 3):

As of October 26, 2018, devices using API level below 16, is quite low(less than 0.5%). Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/)

[image: api levels]

In my opinion, if you target API level 16, you get around 99.5% of all devices. Thats the sweet spot between primitive APIs and latest ones. Almost any open source and popular projects still gives support up to API level 16

Comment: Yes, and I think it also depends on our app's target population/community. If our apps are more likely to be used by middle or upper class, setting a higher minSDK would be appropriate.